# Error in CMD is not displaying properly, How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, cmd, graphql

I am currently doing a graphql,sqlite tutorial, however in my command prompt, it's very difficult to trace the error. It shows bits of my code in the image below but there are numbers and some characters I cannot understand. I need help.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Those are [ANSI Color Codes](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html). PowerShell should render them correctly, but if you want to stick with cmd, use this command to disable color output:

```
npm config set color false
```

Comment: know some shortcuts syntax in cmd and don't want to change, does it works the same way?btw, I tried npm config set color false, but nothing's changed :/